# Is CAS a loop like spin?

Tags: java, c++, jvm

I came across a problem when I read the code of `sun.misc.Unsafe.Java`.

Is CAS a loop like spin?

At first, I think CAS is just an atomic operation in a low-live way. However, when I try to find the source code of the function `compareAndSwapInt`, I find the cpp code like this:

```cpp
jbyte Atomic::cmpxchg(jbyte exchange_value, volatile jbyte* dest, jbyte compare_value) {
    assert(sizeof(jbyte) == 1, "assumption.");
    uintptr_t dest_addr = (uintptr_t)dest;
    uintptr_t offset = dest_addr % sizeof(jint);
    volatile jint* dest_int = (volatile jint*)(dest_addr - offset);
    jint cur = *dest_int;
    jbyte* cur_as_bytes = (jbyte*)(&cur);
    jint new_val = cur;
    jbyte* new_val_as_bytes = (jbyte*)(&new_val);
    new_val_as_bytes[offset] = exchange_value;
    while (cur_as_bytes[offset] == compare_value) {
        jint res = cmpxchg(new_val, dest_int, cur);
        if (res == cur) break;
            cur = res;
        new_val = cur;
        new_val_as_bytes[offset] = exchange_value;
    }
    return cur_as_bytes[offset];
}
```

I saw "when" and "break " in this atomic function.

Is it a spin ways?

related code links:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u20/hotspot/file/190899198332/src/share/vm/prims/unsafe.cpp

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/07011844584f/src/share/classes/sun/misc/Unsafe.java

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u20/hotspot/file/55fb97c4c58d/src/share/vm/runtime/atomic.cpp

Comment: There is no atomic compare and swap byte so it has to be simulated using a loop and a compare and swap int value.

Answer (score 4):

`CAS` is a *single* operation that returns a value of `1` or `0` meaning this operation has made it or not, since you are doing a `compareAndSwapInt` you want this operation to succeed, thus the operations gets repeated until it works.

I think you are also confusing this with a `spin lock`, that basically means do something while this value is "1" (for example); all other threads wait until this value is zero (via `compareAndSwap`), which in effect means that some thread is done with the work and has released the lock (this is referred as `release/acquire` semantics)

Answer (score 4):

The CAS operation is not a spin, it's an atomic operation at hardware level. On x86 and SPARC processors CAS a single instruction, and it supports `int` and `long` operands.

Indeed the `Atomic::cmpxchg` **`int`** / **`long`** overloads are generated on x86 using a single [`cmpxchgl`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/a9b412abe617/src/cpu/x86/vm/stubGenerator_x86_64.cpp#l591)/[`cmpxchgq`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/a9b412abe617/src/cpu/x86/vm/stubGenerator_x86_64.cpp#l617) instruction.

What you're looking at is an `Atomic::cmpxchg` single-**`byte`** overload, which works around the CAS instruction's limitation to simulate CAS at **`byte`** level. It does so by performing a CAS for an `int` located at the same address as the `byte`, then checking just one `byte` out of it and repeating if CAS fails because of a change in the other 3 bytes. The compare-and-swap is still atomic, it just needs to be re-tried sometimes because it covers more bytes than is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

CAS is typically a hardware instruction just like integer addition or comparison, for example (only slower). The instruction itself may be broken down into several steps of so-called microcode, and might indeed contain a low-level loop or a blocking wait for another processor component. However, these are implementation details of the processor architecture. Remember the saying that any problem in CS can be solved by adding another layer of indirection? This also applies here. An atomic operation in Java may actually involve the following layers:

1. The Java method signature.
2. A C(++) JNI method to implement it.
3. A C(++) "compiler intrinsic" such as GCC's `__atomic_compare_exchange`
4. The actual processor instruction.
5. The microcode that implements this instruction.
6. Additional layers to be used by said microcode, such as cache coherency protocols and the like.

My recommendation is not to worry about how all of this works unless either case applies:

- For some reason, it *doesn't* work. This is likely due to a platform bug.
- It is too slow.

Unit tests can help you identify the former case. Benchmarking can help you identify the latter case. But it should be pointed out that if the CAS provided to you by Java is slow, chances are that you will not be able to write a faster one yourself. Therefore, your best bet in this case would be to change your data structures or data flows such as to further reduce the amount of thread synchronization required.